# Check for two different conditions in two lists until the n-th element

Tags: conditional

I have two lists

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 0}; b = {0, 0, 1, 0};
```

and an If-statement and I want to check for two different conditions in these two lists, but only until the n-th element. For `n = 3` it would look like this:

```
If[a[[1]] == 0 && b[[1]] != 0 || a[[2]] == 0 && b[[2]] != 0 || a[[3]] == 0 && b[[3]] != 0, 1, 0]
```

The Output is and should be `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change the Range value, n

```
a = {0, 0, 0, 0};
b = {0, 0, 1, 0};
n=3;
t = 0;
If[Length@Select[Range[n], a[[#]] == 0 && b[[#]] != 0 &] > 0, t = 1];
t
```